# QListView icon mode. Spacing between icons based on size

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qlistview

i'm using Python2.7 + PySide.

Create window with QListView. Set model and for custom viewing created delegate. All work correctly exclude one thing. When i resize window my icons drawing together  from left to right and wrapping to new lines.

But I want that when the size changes between the icons the distance changes and they are all the width of the window

I want alignment by content for my icons. I see in in windows explorer. Icon have fixed size, but spacing changed when window is resized

How to do it?

ps. example 1. Explorer: i resize window. spaces increased. then added one element and spaces set to zero
[image]

[image]

[image]

example2. my window: i resize window. spaces added by right. then new element moved to line

[image]

[image]

[image]

my code:

```
class FileListItemDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(FileListItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent, *args)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red))
        painter.drawRect(option.rect)

        painter.restore()
```

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would also be great to show an image of what you get and want to get

Comment: i use text like a example... you want to see screenshot? it will be 10 pictures and finally i show the same like a my example with text...

Comment: What I have commented are recommendations so that others understand you too, if you do not want to do it well, if you do, maybe I can help you. :P

Comment: maybe you say what dont understand? because i dont know hot to show it... i want to resize window. when i resize it icons stay on his place. when size increase more then one element - one element moved up... 
but in windows explorer not the same. when i resize window - spacing between elements become lagger. and when size increase more then size of one element - it moved up and spacing go to zero... i want the same... change spacing between elements when resize window... element should fill space in window, but not stay left and wait While the size does not allow it to fit the odd element

Comment: Exactly, I do not understand, put an image of what you expect (for example, a couple of images of how windows explorer works in this case), another image of what you get with your current code. And in the end the code that you currently use. :P

Comment: Now I understand, you could place how you have configured the QListView :P

Comment: i'm not configured it... just set to icon view and that's all

Comment: I can not use your code since I do not know what ICON_ROLE or TEXT_ROLE is, what model are you using?

Comment: Make life easy for us, provide an MVCE, that is, a code that can copy or download, execute and observe your problem, many times time is spent on something unnecessary like guessing what the code lacks so that it can be executed.

Comment: that'm my own model and now text role return just name, and icon role return the same text. and you can see - icon role not used in code..... its doesn't matter because i just draw Rect and no more...

Comment: All your items have the same size?

Comment: my idea is to vary the space between items using setSpacing () but until now I find that the general solution is difficult to implement, if you provide me your code could give you a particular answer.